# Path of the FTP server log

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I am using Apache with PHP on a Unix server, and some days back someone changed some PHP files. As part of the investigation, I want to know where the FTP log is saved for the same server so that we can track down the responsible person.

Comment: You are making a mistake by assuming that all file modifications are always done over FTP. It's possible that someone connected using SFTP (which does not log transfers) or edited over SSH directly.

Comment: Or the server was hacked and files were uploaded through a backdoor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have logging properly set up, logs are usually here:

```
/var/log/
```

specify FTP server you are using to get exact path, or look into FTP server config in `/etc/`

- Proftpd: via syslog or `/var/log/proftpd.log` (config: `/etc/proftpd.conf`)
- Pureftpd: `/var/log/pureftpd.log` (config: `/etc/pureftpd/conf/AltLog`)
- Vsftpf: `/var/log/vsftpd.log` (config: `/etc/vsftpd.conf`)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I got Access and error logs in /works folder.